# Remove rows from data frame using row indices where row indices might be zero length vector

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to drop some rows from some dataframe using numeric indices of the rows. But sometimes the indices vector that I am going to drop becomes zero length vector. In this case, I expect that nothing should be dropped from the original data frame. But instead of nothing everything is dropped.

For example, here `drop` works as expected

```
df = data_frame( a = 10:12 )
drop = c(1,2)
df[ -drop, ]
# # A tibble: 1 × 1
# a
# <int>
# 1    12
```

But when `drop` is zero length vector, then removing those rows doesn't work as I expect.

```
drop = integer()
df[ -drop, ]
# A tibble: 0 × 1
# ... with 1 variables: a <int>
```

I was expecting to get the whole `df` object without any modification.

How to remove rows from a data frame using row indices safely where row indices might become a zero length vector?

Comment: If `x` is a zero length vector, then `-x` is also a zero length vector. There's no difference between them. You can either test for a zero length vector or you can `setdiff` the indexes you want to drop: `df[ setdiff(1:nrow(df), drop), ]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For this reason, it is better to use `%in%` and negate `!` it

```
df[!seq_len(nrow(df)) %in% drop, ]
```

---

As it is a `data_frame`, we can use `tidyverse` methods

```
df %>%
   filter(!row_number() %in% drop)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following simple code works fine !

```
df   <- data.frame(a = 10:12)
drop <-  c(1,2)
'if'(length(drop) == 0, df, df[-drop, ])

drop <-  integer()
'if'(length(drop) == 0, df, df[-drop, ])
```