# Remove rows with specific row numbers using dplyr's pipe function

Tags: r

I am looking for some way to delete specific rows by row numbers using `dplyr's pipe` function

```
library(dplyr)
head(mtcars)
```

Now let say I want remove row numbers `c(1, 4, 7)`. Typically we would use `mtcars[-c(1, 4, 7), ]` to do the same.

However I want to use `pipe` to do the same.

Is there any way to do this?

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Remove rows from data frame using row indices where row indices might be zero length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44265783/remove-rows-from-data-frame-using-row-indices-where-row-indices-might-be-zero-le)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
   slice(-c(1, 4, 7))
```

---

Or if we want to use `[`

```
mtcars %>%
      `[`(-c(1, 4, 7),)
```

---

Or use `extract` from `magrittr`

```
library(magrittr)
mtcars %>%
    extract(-c(1, 4, 7),)
```

Answer (score 4):

We could use `filter`

```
library(dplyr)

# vector for rows to remove
to_remove <- c(1, 4, 7)

mtcars %>%
  filter(!row_number() %in% to_remove)
```